# Counting the results of Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I have a job that goes off and checks for specified windows processes that have taken over 5 minutes of CPU time, across a range of servers.

The processes and servers are supplied via arrays, and looped through with some loops, this works nicely.

However, what I want to do is count how many results are found for each process as it loops through.

For the purpose of this example, the set variables would be

```
$seconds = 300
$server = "SERVER1"
$process = "notepad.exe"
```

And the command I run is as follows

```
$list = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
    Param($Rseconds, $Rprocess)
    Get-Process | Where {
        ($_.CPU -gt $Rseconds) -and
        ($_.Path -like "*$Rprocess”)
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Kill()
    }
} -ArgumentList $seconds, $process)
```

As far as killing the process, it works perfectly, and respects the values input, but what I can't get it to do is count how many of each process it killed

I've tried simply incrementing a counter within the `ForEach-Object` block, and tried sticking `Measure-Object` in various places to try and return a value, so I can call on something like

```
$list.Count
```

But nothing seems to work.  It simply returns a blank value.

Comment: Would you like to pull some information from event viewer? By adding a condition to call the event!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stop-Process` with the parameter `-PassThru` instead of calling `Kill()` in a loop.

```
$list = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { 
    Param($Rseconds, $Rprocess)
    Get-Process | Where-Object {
        $_.CPU -gt $Rseconds -and
        $_.Path -like "*$Rprocess"
    } | Stop-Process -Force -PassThru
} -ArgumentList $seconds, $process
```

If you want only the count returned instead of a list of process objects you could do something like this instead:

```
$list = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { 
    Param($Rseconds, $Rprocess)
    $proc = Get-Process | Where-Object {
        $_.CPU -gt $Rseconds -and
        $_.Path -like "*$Rprocess"
    }
    $proc | Stop-Process -Force
    $proc.Count
} -ArgumentList $seconds, $process
```

Comment: OK, will give this a go. Main thing is I have it working for now, but does this answer actual get me the count I requested?

Comment: @addy4488 No, it will return the process objects, since you seemed to want to use `$list.Count` in the outer scope. See my updated answer for how to return just the count.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this

```
$listCount = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { param($Rseconds,$Rprocess) Get-Process | Where { ($_.CPU -gt $Rseconds) -and ($_.Path -like "*$Rprocess”) }  | Measure-Object } -ArgumentList $seconds,$process)
```

Had to add in the Measure-Object, but I was also being fooled by my own setup. I'd limited the server scope to one server, but I was checking the wrong one, so led myself down a blind alley, and seems I'd had the solution previously anyway

All working now